# Pip installing packages no longer works on RPi after switching routers

Tags: python, ssl, pip, raspberry-pi3

So recently, I've upgraded my internet plan and so my ISP had to switch my router because my old one was not capable of handeling the new speed. In the morning of the day the ISP technitian went to switch the router, I had updated `aioredis` (and `aiohttp` as it was a requirement). However in the afternoon, after the routers had been switched, I was no longer able to update another core lib I was using in my project. I did `pip install -U libneko` and I got the following message

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/libneko/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/libneko/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/libneko/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/libneko/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/libneko/
Requirement already up-to-date: libneko in ./lib/python3.7/site-packages (-)
```

And I got pretty confused as this had never happened to me before. I did some researching and I all I could find was that it could be some SSL issue but I also found [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5374).
The weird thing is that I updated SSL recently (doing `python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"` on my python 3.7 virtualenv outputs `OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017`).

I tried to test if this was a general SSL problem so I did `wget gnu.org` and got the `indext.html` with no problem. However, when trying to do `wget files.pythonhosted.org` or `wget pypi.org` gets me this

```
--2018-08-24 21:07:06--  http://pythonhosted.org/
Resolving pythonhosted.org (pythonhosted.org)... 2a04:4e42:600::319, 2a04:4e42:400::319, 2a04:4e42:200::319, ...
Connecting to pythonhosted.org (pythonhosted.org)|2a04:4e42:600::319|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://pythonhosted.org/ [following]
--2018-08-24 21:07:06--  https://pythonhosted.org/
Connecting to pythonhosted.org (pythonhosted.org)|2a04:4e42:600::319|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: Error in the pull function.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

--2018-08-24 21:07:14--  http://pypi.org/
Resolving pypi.org (pypi.org)... 2a04:4e42:200::223, 2a04:4e42::223, 2a04:4e42:400::223, ...
Connecting to pypi.org (pypi.org)|2a04:4e42:200::223|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://pypi.org/ [following]
--2018-08-24 21:07:14--  https://pypi.org/
Connecting to pypi.org (pypi.org)|2a04:4e42:200::223|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: Error in the pull function.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

So... I'm a bit confused now. Does someone have an idea what this is?

Also my RPi is running NextCloudPi v0.46.0 (I know it's outdated but I intend to do a clean reinstall cus my nextcloud got all borked sometime ago because of me doing a mistake on the setup).

Comment: Have you tried to `ping` an IPv4 address, as well as an IPv6 address? Something might be wrong with the IPv6 configuration.

Comment: Pinging both `8.8.8.8` and `2001:4860:4860::8888` seems fine.